# Qt/Qml Error - Qml module not found(QtQuick.Controls.Material)

Tags: ubuntu, python, c++, python3, qt

I recently decided to try out creating a gui for python with pyside and qml. I installed pyqt5, pyside2, qt designer and qt creator. The code I tried seems to work well, however, when I try to use the material design style, I get an error that the module isn't found.

My questions is that is there a fix for it. Or is it possible to download a material stylesheet and kind of reference it.

Note:: I did research on this topic and found similar issues on various websites, however, none of the solutions helped.

I am using ubuntu 18 and this is the code i am trying:
QML::
[Link to QML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUdWY.png)
Python::
[Link to Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlB8Y.png)